# Can anyone tell which PANTONE color is the thread/terry in the picture?

Tags: designers, color-spaces, pantone, information-graphics, embroidery

I am loonking for the PANTONE color that matches the color og the stiching/terry in the picture.

[image]

I did my search and found 2 white colors:

1. Brilliant white 11-4001 TPG.
2. Bright white 18-4004 TCX.

I do not think this is the right color.
Any advice?

Many thanks,

Comment: It's not possible to accurately match colours by looking at a photo. You should use a Patone Color book to match the swatches against the physical material.

Comment: There are very many color values in that "white." You will need to average it somehow.